# How to use regex to solve this word count problem in dart?

Tags: regex, dart

Doing an exercise and trying to get all the cases.

Given a phrase, count the occurrences of each word in that phrase.

For example for the input "olly olly in come free"

```
olly: 2

in: 1

come: 1

free: 1
```

Here what I get so far:

```
Map<String, int> countWords(String words) {
var wordCount = Map<String, int>();

words.split(RegExp(r"\W")).forEach(
  (word) {
    wordCount.update(word.toLowerCase(), (value) => value + 1,
        ifAbsent: () => 1);
  },
);
return wordCount;}
```

So it works for simple sentences but not words with newlines, punctuation, etc.

Cases like this:

```
'one,\ntwo,\nthree'
'car: carpet as java: javascript!!&@\$%^&'
'Joe can\'t tell between \'large\' and large.'
'testing, 1, 2 testing'
'First: don\'t laugh. Then: don\'t cry.'
'Joe can\'t tell between app, apple and a.'
' multiple   whitespaces'
',\n,one,\n ,two \n \'three\''
```

Im not good with regex so I'm not sure what I'm missing. Please help me find a solution, thanks.

Comment: It's a non-trivial problem, probably not solved by a regex that fits in half a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of splitting the string using each non-word character just get the words:

```dart
  var wordCount = {};
  for (var match in RegExp(r"\w+('\w+)?").allMatches('my& string with with symbols&%!1')) {
     wordCount.update(match.group(0).toLowerCase(), (value) => value + 1,
        ifAbsent: () => 1);
  }
  print(wordCount);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. This solution is close but for the 3 cases where the ' is escaped. Like 'Joe can\'t tell between app, apple and a.', 'Joe can\'t tell between \'large\' and large.', and 'First: don\'t laugh. Then: don\'t cry.'. What would I need to add to include that?

Comment: do you want to match `can't` as a single word? And should the `'s` count as a different word (eg Mattia and Mattia's)?

Comment: Yes. Stuff like Mattia's, don't, cant, etc should be a single word. Heres and example of the output of the test "Expected: {'joe': 1, 'can\'t': 1, 'tell': 1, 'between': 1, 'large': 2, 'and': 1}
  Actual: {'joe': 1, 'can': 1, 't': 1, 'tell': 1, 'between': 1, 'large': 2, 'and': 1}
   Which: has different length and is missing map key 'can\'t'"

Comment: Maybe you need to allow more than one apostrophe in each word. You wouldn't've though it possible, but it is :)